# How to check if the given value exists in array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check if the given value is present in array or not.
Here i have a function where in i will pass one value as parameter.
i have a array `$_SESSION['cart']` where i have stored multiple values,while iterating the array i want to check if the product_id is in array

i am calling function while iterating array to check if product_id exists

```
    <?php
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $item):
        getCartitems($item);
        endforeach;
    ?>
```

function

```
function productIncart($product_id){
        //check if the $_SESSION['cart']; has the given product id
        //if yes 
        //return true
        //else
        //return false
}
```

how can i do this?

Comment: How your data is structured in `$_SESSION['cart']`?

Answer (score 2):

You can see if a given key of an array is set using the [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function.

```
<?php
$array = array( "foo" => "bar" );

if( isset( $array["foo"] ) )
{
echo $array["foo"]; // Outputs bar
}

if( isset( $array["orange"] ) )
{
 echo $array["orange"]; 
} else {
 echo "Oranges does not exist in this array!";
}
```

To check if a given value is in an array, you may use the [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function.

```
 if (in_array($product_id, $_SESSION["cart"]))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false";
  }
```

Comment: Why not just `return in_array($product_id, $_SESSION["cart"])`? `if(bool) { return true; } else { return false; }` is just a long way of writing `return bool;`.

Comment: why even return it? Why not just make a shorthand? Why even check the array, in a prober designed piece of software, you are not in doubt of whats in your arrays.  From a learning perspective, this makes alot more sense :) But point taken. Dont be pedagogic on Stackoverflow! :D

Answer (score 2):

`in_array` returns `true` if the item is present in the array else `false`. You can try this -

```
function productIncart($product_id){
    return in_array($product_id, $_SESSION['cart']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function productIncart($product_id){
  if (in_array($product_id, $_SESSION['cart']))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false";
  }
}
```